# Simplifying $\cot(\beta - \gamma)\cot(\gamma - \alpha) + \cos(\gamma - \alpha)\cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)\cot(\beta - \gamma) $

Tags: trigonometry

> I have a homework question which asks to simplify the following expression:
>
> $$\cot(\beta - \gamma)\cot(\gamma - \alpha) + \cos(\gamma - \alpha)\cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)\cot(\beta - \gamma) $$

There are no restrictions placed on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ except that they take real values.

I tried to solve the question by writing $\cot$ as $\dfrac{\cos}{\sin}$ and using product to sum formulae but instead of being simplified the expression only became more humongous.

How should I proceed with the question? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

**Edit**:
The expression as stated is incorrect and has no further simplification, as told by Somos. I confirmed it with my teacher. The cosines should be cotangents, which is simplified as told by Lab Bhattacharjee.

Comment: Just checking: Are you sure that all your "$\cos$"s and "$\cot$"s are correct?

Comment: Maybe writing $a=\beta-\gamma$, $b=\gamma-\alpha$ and $c=\alpha-\beta$ helps. Your expression now is in terms of $a$,$b$ and $c$ with $a+b+c=0$.

Comment: https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Trigonometry/proof-of-cotacotb-cotbcotc-cotccota-1_97408.htm

Comment: @Blue Yeah they are all correct

Comment: If the expression you have is **truly** correct, then there is no way to simplify it. However, if the last $\cos$ is replace by $\cot$ then it factors. Please **double** check. Another comment noticed that if **all** of the $\cos$ replaced by $\cot$ it simplifies to $1$.

Comment: @Somos I know, when I tried to simplify it, I was suspicious that there is something amiss. What I have written is the correct question. If you say that there is no possible simplification, do write that in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *a priori* difficult to solve "simplify" problems because there is no precise standard definition of how one expression is simpler than another. Even if there were such a definition, it is difficult to **prove** that an expression is already as simple as possible without some theory. Despite this, many computer algebra systems implement some form of  a "simplify" command.

For your given expression

$$ \cot(\beta - \gamma)\cot(\gamma - \alpha) + \cos(\gamma - \alpha)\cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)\cot(\beta - \gamma) \tag1 $$

it seems that this can not be simplified according to `Mathematica`. As a sum of products of three pairs of trigonometric functions it is about as simple as it can be. Given this, it is possible that there was a misprint and some of the $\cos$ should be $\cot$ or vice versa.

If the last $\cos$ was changed to $\cot$, then there is a factorization

$$ \cot(\beta - \gamma)\cot(\gamma - \alpha) + \cos(\gamma - \alpha)\cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cot(\alpha - \beta)\cot(\beta - \gamma) = (\cos(\beta-\gamma) + \sin(2(\alpha-\beta))/4) \frac{ \sin(2(\alpha-\gamma)) }
{\sin(\alpha-\beta) \sin(\alpha-\gamma) } \tag2 $$

but it does not seem that the product is simpler than the triple sum.

If **all** of the $\cos$ were changed to $\cot$ then the result

$$ \cot(\beta - \gamma)\cot(\gamma - \alpha) + \cot(\gamma - \alpha)\cot(\alpha - \beta) + \cot(\alpha - \beta)\cot(\beta - \gamma) = 1 \tag3 $$

is as simple as you can get except for $0$. The question has severe problems and is almost certain that it was incorrectly stated.

Comment: Thanks; I'll be sure to check about this question with my sir when I submit my work and comment what he says